# Using Selenium to get past dropdown (md-select)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm stuck with a dropdown that I can't get pass in Selenium.
I'm trying to collect some price data using Selenium from this link: 
https://xxx. In this link, you need to click on a button (Next), then select any option in the subsequent dropdown, then press (Next) again to advance into the information page that I wanted to collect some information. I'm stuck at the dropdown - I am unable to select any option.

This is my code thus far:

```
browser.get("https://xxx/#/pricePlans/step1")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
while True:
    try:        
        button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.md-dialog-container.ng-scope > md-dialog > md-dialog-actions > div > button')
    except TimeoutException:
        break    
    button.click()
    options_box= browser.find_element_by_class_name('bullet-content-title')
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
    options_box.click()
```

The issue lies with the dropdown options (It has options like HDB 1-room, HDB 2-room etc). I tried to reference the option box by XPATH, CSS selector, class_name (as seen above) but with the snippet above, Spyder issues time-out. Other snippets I tried included:

```
ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "bullet-content-title")))
```

using XPATH, class_name but no luck.
I'm a newbie at web scraping who got thus far by searching the SO, but I am unable to find much solutions regarding (md-select) dropdowns.
I also attempted to use

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(options_box).click(options_box)
```

but I did not see any clicking nor mouse movements so i'm stumped. 
I appreciate any advice at this point of time. Thank you so much!

Edit:
Code Snippets and Responses:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--incognito')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe', options=option)
browser.get("https://xxx")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

while True:
    try:        
        button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.md-dialog-container.ng-scope > md-dialog > md-dialog-actions > div > button')
    except TimeoutException:
        break    
    button.click()


    options_box = browser.find_element_by_class_name('bullet-content-title')
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
    options_box.click()
```

This returns "StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"
Which I assume it is due to the presence of the second "Next" Button which is inert at the moment.

```
options_box = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "bullet-content-title")))  
options_box.click()
```

Does nothing. Spyder eventually returned me TimeOut Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AndrewRay answer is good for getting the value but not for selecting the options. you can do this to select the options.

```
#browser.get("https://......")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

try:        
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.green-btn').click()
    # wait until dialog dissapear
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'md-dialog[aria-describedby="dialogContent_0"]')))
    # click the dropdown
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('md-input-container').click()
    # select the option element
    setOptionElement = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('md-option[value="HDB Executive"]')
    # need to scrollIntoView if the option in the bottom
    # or you get error the element not clickable
    browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();arguments[0].click()', setOptionElement)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes. This works for selecting an option. Maybe I wasn't too clear in my comments just now in my excitement. Thanks @ewwink!

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.get('https://compare.openelectricitymarket.sg/#/pricePlans/step1')
time.sleep(5)  

next_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.green-btn')  
next_btn.click()  

dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id('select_4')  
options = dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('md-option')  

for option in options:  
   print option.get_attribute('value')
```

Hope this helps. Use the .get_attribute method to find the value of the option and click that option if matches the desired value. :)

Comment: added a new answer since you cannot format code in the comment section on SO, so here you go! :)

Comment: Hi Andrew, 
it's looking good! Hmm looking at your code, so it appears that I've been finding the wrong element?

Comment: It just seems that you found the element, but tried clicking on the dropdown itself, but the options of the dropdown are located within the html, but hidden until clicked, therefore you can just click on the option in the backend and it will appear in the dropdown. No clicking on the dropdown itself necessary.

Comment: Hi Andrew, 
do you have any idea how to select any one of the options in the dropdown?

Comment: when i used the following addons:
for option in options:  
   if option.get_attribute('value')=='HDB 4-Room':
       option.click()
i get a "ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable"